# ArcGIS Server 10 installation in Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL)

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, linux

The ArcGIS Server 10 system requirements page says that it supports Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) AS/ES 4 and RHEL 5. I have RHEL WS 4, RHEL WS 6, and RHEL Desktop 5. I am not sure if any of these version works well with ArcGIS Server 10 without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Future Proof yourself

ArcGIS 10.1 (including Server)

ArcGIS Server 10.1 will no longer support SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS/ES 4.  **However, we will support SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 5.**

http://blog.joesonic.com/2011/08/arcgis-101-beta-launch-and-deprecation.html

Offical Source:
"Considerations for ArcGIS Server developers: A look toward 10.1"

http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/04/27/considerations-for-arcgis-server-developers-a-look-toward-10-1/

Answer (score 1):

you can check out [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgisserver/10.0/arcgis-server-server-requirements).

[image: support]

i hope it helps you..